# What is the name of this light sans-serif typeface?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Can anyone help me to identify the font of these letters? It is a light sans-serif typeface.

[image]

Comment: WhatTheFont completely fails with this, and Identifont doesn't help either. There aren't really enough letters. Do you have a reference you can add to the question? Where did this example come from?

Comment: That dot on the i is weird...looks like a tiny heart almost. It's close to Freight Sans also but it's not it.

Answer (score 2):

The font is close to

**Thesans Classic** or **Light** or "Hair"

[image]

**TheSans Hair**

[image]

Comment: It's not the same but very similar.Thanks a lot friend ;)

Comment: that's... rather different. The g's and r's flags, length of the s and general balance are way different.

Comment: Bit harsh to downvote as "Not useful". I reckon this **is** useful.